# processing duplicates on different partition and offset in kafa consumer application

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are trying to consume records from our producers. It has 2 partitions as of now but it can get increased in future to improve our throughput. We are trying to consume records with 2 consumer threads but we are getting duplicate. Our producers are saying they had included key also but still it's not fixing issue. Not sure why ?

But, from consumer end, because of duplicates , our whole process cycle is getting triggered twice which we would want to avoid. Our concern is if we increase partitions in future, it will increase duplicates as well.

**Our process cycle :**

Getting records from stream -- > Upsert in a table based on key --> fetch records based on key and insert it into a table --> call api and update records

**Log :**

```
coming from stream :004582777into offset 500405and partition 0
coming from stream :004582777into offset 499525and partition 1
skipping tax id 004582777
skipping tax id 004582777
coming from stream :002402419into offset 499526and partition 1
coming from stream :002402419into offset 500406and partition 0
skipping tax id 002402419
skipping tax id 002402419
coming from stream :010546936into offset 499527and partition 1
coming from stream :010546936into offset 500407and partition 0
skipping tax id 010546936
skipping tax id 010546936
coming from stream :010646378into offset 500408and partition 0
coming from stream :010646378into offset 499528and partition 1
skipping tax id 010646378
skipping tax id 010646378
coming from stream :010866219into offset 500409and partition 0
coming from stream :010866219into offset 499529and partition 1
skipping tax id 010866219
skipping tax id 010866219
coming from stream :019541747into offset 499530and partition 1
coming from stream :019541747into offset 500410and partition 0
skipping tax id 019541747
skipping tax id 019541747
coming from stream :020438119into offset 500411and partition 0
coming from stream :020438119into offset 499531and partition 1
skipping tax id 020438119
skipping tax id 020438119
coming from stream :020594385into offset 499532and partition 1
coming from stream :020594385into offset 500412and partition 0
skipping tax id 020594385
skipping tax id 020594385
coming from stream :043514479into offset 500413and partition 0
coming from stream :043514479into offset 499533and partition 1
skipping tax id 043514479
skipping tax id 043514479
coming from stream :030446242into offset 500414and partition 0
coming from stream :030446242into offset 499534and partition 1
record count is more than zero :1 for tax id:030446242 <--- we are calling API 2 times because of 2 ocurance
record count is more than zero :1 for tax id:030446242
```

How can we make sure to pick only occurrence of this record even if we are getting duplicate from different partition ? As both are records are getting processed by 2 consumer threads in parallel, for some records it's capturing both instances in table and for some only 1.

**Code :**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${app.topic}", groupId = "${app.group_id_config}")
    public void run(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgement) throws Exception {

        try {
                prov_tin_number         = record.value().get("providerTinNumber").toString();
                prov_tin_type           = record.value().get("providerTINType").toString();
                enroll_type             = record.value().get("enrollmentType").toString();
                vcp_prov_choice_ind     = record.value().get("vcpProvChoiceInd").toString();
                error_flag              = "";

                dataexecutor.peStremUpsertTbl(prov_tin_number, prov_tin_type, enroll_type, vcp_prov_choice_ind, error_flag,
                    record.partition(), record.offset());
                
            
                acknowledgement.acknowledge();
                    
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(record);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> getting duplicate from different partition

Kafka knows nothing about the data; you will get all records at all partitions/offsets.

You can add an implementation of `FilterStrategy` to the listener container factory to filter out duplicates. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#filtering-messages

Comment: Thanks Gary. As I am new to this, just wanted to check whether this would automatically consider one value from a partition and ignore rest coming from other partitions ? It seems like I have to store key and value and then compare it ? but as all consumer threads would run in parallel(2 in my case) ? would this work ? any code example would be helpful..

Comment: Yes, you will have to synchronize the idempotency check in that case.